# Issue with pushing data to array in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, knockout.js

In my HTML page there are 3 inputs. Using the user inputs, I wish to update elements of my page using KnockoutJS. This is the script I have written:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function Task(data){
        this.goal=ko.observable(data.goal);
        this.type=ko.observable(data.type);
        this.date=ko.observable(data.date);
        console.log("Data"+ " " + data.goal);

    }



    var myViewModel=function(tasks){
        var self=this;
        self.tasks=ko.observableArray([{goal:"abc", type:"Intermediate", date:"12/13/1122"}]);
        self.newGoalText=ko.observable("");
        self.newTypeText=ko.observable("");
        self.newDateText=ko.observable("");


        self.addTask=function(){
            self.tasks.push(new Task({goal:this.newGoalText(),type:this.newTypeText(), date:this.newDateText()}));

            console.log(tasks);

        self.newGoalText("");
        self.newTypeText("");
        self.newDateText("");


    }//addTask function

    }//viewModel


    ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel())

});
```

The console.log tells me that the values are being obtained from user as expected. However, the "push" method on the tasks array seem to have no effect at all. Please guide me.

Comment: The problem might lie in your html, so it would be helpful if you post it. I tested your code (didn't change anything) and it worked with the markup I provided. see https://jsfiddle.net/ffojupuf/

Comment: @Adrian, thanks for your help. My HTML code was similar to yours and i didn't find much of a difference wrt bindings. Wonder what went wrong though! I used "value" instead of "textInput". That was the only difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing to your array a Task, you have to do everytime, so, when you initialize, you have to use `[new Task({...}), new Task({...})]`

Your `console.log(tasks);` is not correct. This is showing your tasks variable, not your self.tasks, what i'm wondering you want to show, so be careful with your variable names and with (none)varname vs this.varname vs self.varname or you will have so much headaches...

finally [here you are](https://jsfiddle.net/Tistklehoff/o7f3n5k1/11/) your example fully working.

I hope this help you.

Regards.